# How to create a button in jquery, having its href attribute equal to ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Having ajax request like:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'mysite/action',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: postData,
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response);
    var input = $('<a class="btn btn-info" href="....response...." role="button">Link</a>');
    input.appendTo($("body"));
  }
});
```

I get a link in ajax response, how do I create a button having its href attribute equal to that ajax response?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also pass attributes in an object, which will take care of saniziting strings for you, such as escaping quotes:

```
$('<a/>', {
   'class': 'btn btn-info',
   href: response,
   role: 'button',
   text: 'Link'
}).appendTo('body');
```

---

In response to comment below, simply pass a similarly constructed span to `append`. Compared to the example below, I've removed the `text` property from the attributes object, and add the link text in a subsequent `append` call, to insert the icon before the text, if this is what you want.

It could of course have been achieved by adding the span with a `prepend` instead, if you want to keep the text property, but I think it makes more semantical sense to add the elements in the order you want them to appear.

```
$('<a/>', {
   'class': 'btn btn-info',
   href: response,
   role: 'button'
}).append(
   $('<span/>', { 'class': 'glyphicon glyphicon-download' })
).append(' Link')
 .appendTo('body');
```

Comment: very nice answer

Comment: If I want to add ´<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download"></span>´ inside the  ´<a> ´  tag, How would I do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Template Strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

> Template literals are string literals allowing embedded expressions

```
var input = $(`<a class="btn btn-info" href="${response}" role="button">Link</a>`);
```

Or you can use the `+` operator and break string into to parts.

```
var input = $('<a class="btn btn-info" href="'+15+'"role="button">Link</a>');
```

Comment: You can only use template literals if you are building down to ES5 with babel otherwise you get browser incompatibility. Unlikely for someone still using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'mysite/action',
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: postData,                     
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        console.log(response);
                        var input = $('<a class="btn btn-info" href="' + response + '" role="button">Link</a>');
                        input.appendTo($("body"));                      

                    }                       
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let response = 'http://google.com';
var input = $('<a class="btn btn-info" href="' + response + '" role="button">Link</a>');
input.appendTo($("body"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```